# Can't launch IDLE after installing Enthought Canopy

Tags: enthought

I was previously running Enthought EPD 7.3.2, but switched over to Canopy (academic license). I completely uninstalled EPD before running the Canopy install.

After installing Canopy, I have a shortcut to IDLE in the Canopy start menu folder, but I can't get it to launch (I click it and nothing happens). Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Canopy, but am having the same issue.

Running the 64-bit version of Canopy on Win7, 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canopy 1.0 and 1.0.1 versions have problems with `tcl` and `TKinter`, and IDLE doesn't work.  This should be fixed in an update, which is just round the corner.

As an afterthought, is there a specific reason you wish to use IDLE?  Canopy's editor comes integrated with an IPython console (along with many other goodies), which gives a much better user experience while programming, IMO. (Disclaimer: I work for Enthought)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And my reason for using IDLE is actually the lack of the features you describe. I'm running a Web crawler written in Python, and it's easier to run the code in IDLE than in Windows command prompt for my purposed (e.g. if it crashes I need to be able to look back at where things left off). I know this could be solved by some better logging than I'm doing now, but it's a strategy that's been working for now.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and found a very simple solution. Try it out and see if it works in your situation too. There is a directory for the Canopy installation:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.7.4.3348.win-x86_64\Lib\idlelib

Find “idle.ico” file there, copy and paste it into “Icons” subdirectory.
This fixed the problem!

Comment: thanks, this worked for me too. I can't imagine how you discovered the fix. (Maybe running it through a debugger?)